# Look for "x" in column X, instead of in column A

Tags: excel, vba

The code works as it should, had help with the array part (thanks again, CDP1802!). But instead of having to read "x" in column A, it has to read it in column X.

I thought I understood the array part, but this shows I don't... I can't figure it out for the life of me.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Acto_Export()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim SystemlistFilename As String, SystemlistSheetname
    Dim ProjectNumber As String
    Dim n As Long, r As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    
    SystemlistFilename = wb.Name
    SystemlistSheetname = ws.Name
    
    'Get the project number from the active sheet
    If WorksheetFunction.IsText(ws.Range("C4")) Or Len(ws.Range("C4")) <> 8 Then
         MsgBox ("Wrong value given. No file created. please use a valid project number in C4")
         Exit Sub
    End If
    ProjectNumber = ws.Range("C4")
    
    ' output column names
    Dim dictCol As Object
    Set dictCol = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With dictCol
        .Add "ProjectNummer", 1
        .Add "Activiteit", 2
        .Add "ActiviteitNaam", 3
        .Add "ActiviteitSoort", 4
        .Add "Bouwdeel", 5
        .Add "BouwdeelOmschrijving", 6
        .Add "BouwdeelZoeknaam", 7
        .Add "ActiviteitSoortNaam", 8
        .Add "ZoeknaamActiviteitSoort", 9
        .Add "Categorie", 10
        .Add "CategorieNaam", 11
        .Add "Projectdeel", 12
    End With
    
    ' initial rows
    Const indIMP = 9
    Const indEXP = 2
    
    Dim arList, arOut
    With ws
        ' array of list data
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        arList = .Range("A1:F" & lastrow)
        ' array to hold output
        ReDim arOut(1 To lastrow, 1 To dictCol.Count)
    End With
      
    ' output header
    Dim arHeader
    arHeader = Array("Activiteit", "ActiviteitNaam", "ProjectNummer", _
        "ActiviteitSoort", "Bouwdeel", "BouwdeelOmschrijving", _
        "BouwdeelZoeknaam", "ActiviteitSoortNaam", "ZoeknaamActiviteitSoort", _
        "Categorie", "CategorieNaam", "Projectdeel")
        
    'Loop through data in the source sheet
    For r = indIMP To lastrow
            
        If LCase(arList(r, 1)) = "x" Then
            n = n + 1
            arOut(n, dictCol("Activiteit")) = "00" & arList(r, 2)
            arOut(n, dictCol("ActiviteitNaam")) = arList(r, 6)
            arOut(n, dictCol("ProjectNummer")) = "00" & ProjectNumber
            arOut(n, dictCol("ActiviteitSoort")) = "00" & arList(r, 2)
            arOut(n, dictCol("Bouwdeel")) = 0
            arOut(n, dictCol("BouwdeelOmschrijving")) = "algemeen"
            arOut(n, dictCol("BouwdeelZoeknaam")) = "alg"
            arOut(n, dictCol("ActiviteitSoortNaam")) = arList(r, 6)
            arOut(n, dictCol("ZoeknaamActiviteitSoort")) = Mid(arList(r, 6), 1, 2)
            arOut(n, dictCol("Categorie")) = 0
            arOut(n, dictCol("CategorieNaam")) = "algemeen"
            arOut(n, dictCol("Projectdeel")) = 0
        ElseIf Len(arList(r, 1)) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Wrong value given. No file was created. please use X : ", _
                   vbExclamation, "Error in row " & r
              
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
    Next

    ' create output file
    Dim wbACTO As Workbook, wsACTO As Worksheet
    Dim sFolder As String, ExportFileName As String
    If n > 0 Then
        ' select output folder
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
            If .Show = -1 Then        ' if OK is pressed
                sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
            End If
        End With
        If sFolder = "" Then        ' if an error occured
            MsgBox ("No folder was selected")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    
        ' create new workbook
        Set wbACTO = Workbooks.Add(1)
        Set wsACTO = wbACTO.Sheets(1)
        
        ' add header
        With wsACTO ' 12 colunms
            ' Rename the export sheet
            .Name = "PLN961"
            .Range("A1:L1") = arHeader
                           
            ' Set number formats for specific columns
            .Columns("B:K").NumberFormat = "000000"
            .Columns("E:E").NumberFormat = "0"
            .Columns("I:J").NumberFormat = "0"
            .Columns("L:L").NumberFormat = "0"
            
            ' write output
            .Cells(indEXP, 1).Resize(n, UBound(arOut, 2)) = arOut
        End With
        
        ' Save the export file
        ExportFileName = sFolder & "\" & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss_") & ProjectNumber & "_importfileActo.xlsx"
        wbACTO.SaveAs ExportFileName
        MsgBox n & " rows written to " & ExportFileName, vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs ")
    Else
        MsgBox "No output to create", vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub
```

I thought it was as easy as changing `If LCase(arList(r, 1)) = "x" Then` to `If LCase(arList(r, 24)) = "x" Then` or `If LCase(arList(24, 1)) = "x" Then` but this doesn't seem to work.

Normally I'd try to re-learn arrays and maybe fix it myself, but I don't really have time to do that.

Summary: how do I change my code to look for "x" in column X, instead of column A?

Comment: `arList = .Range("A1:F" & lastrow)` if you want to read from ColX  then you need to include that in the range which `arList` is created from.  So `arList = .Range("A1:X" & lastrow)`

Comment: Currently `arList` doesn't have column X.

Comment: added in X in the arList, but still that doesn't work... it doesn't give me the error now, but it shows X always empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine the change noted by @TimWilliams and by @Mikku with the change you have noted yourself. That is change

```
arList = .Range("A1:F" & lastrow)
```

to

```
arList = .Range("A1:X" & lastrow)
```

so that the data for column X is included in the array, then change

```
If LCase(arList(r, 1)) = "x" Then
```

to

```
If LCase(arList(r, 24)) = "x" Then
```

which then checks in the 24th 'column' of data (ie so the equivalent of column X)